# drupal taxonomy term path to return alias

Tags: drupal, taxonomy

Taxonomy term path:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/taxonomy_term_path

Returns the unaliased path. I used pathauto to give the term alias, how can I return the aliased version?

Thanks.

Comment: Check my answer here [on how to use taxonomy entity index][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12640937/438977

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [drupal_get_path_alias()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_path_alias/6)

```
$path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias(taxonomy_term_path($term) );
```

Comment: `taxonomy_term_path()` is for Drupal 6 only. For Drupal 7 use: `taxonomy_term_uri()` however it wants a term object, so you may need to use it like this: 

`drupal_get_path_alias(taxonomy_term_uri($term))` where $term needs to be the term object or you can fake it with `$term = (object) array('tid' => $tid)` (provided you know the tid!)

Answer (score 1):

you may want to explore the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/url/6) function as well.
I use it all of the time with node ids.

`$node_href = url('node/'.$nid);`

**although you probably want something like:**

```
$term_href = url('taxonomy/term/' . $tid);
```